# Perl program to connect oracle database from different system

Tags: oracle, perl, activeperl, perlapp, perldb

I have a perl program which connects to oracle database and fetch details,Which is perfectly working from same host(cu394.cloud.net)

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect( "dbi:Oracle:host=cu394.cloud.net;sid=ora", "ctfuser238", "ctfuser238" , {'RaiseError' => 1});
```

But I need to run this same program from different host (cu364.cloud.net) to connect to cu394.

I tried make this script as executable binary like this using perlapp

```
/opt/pdk/bin/perlapp --force --exe rms --perl /opt/ActivePerl-5.12/bin/perl-static update.pl
```

and tried running that executable from different server but no luck

Kindly throw some light on this

Best Regards
Sathish

Comment: does our Oracle instance allow connections from outside?

Comment: yes that oracle is accessible from outside

Comment: BTW, why do you need an exe on other host? In current situation problem may be anywhere. try to connect like: `my $dbh = DBI->connect( "dbi:Oracle:host=cu394.cloud.net;sid=ora", "ctfuser238", "ctfuser238" , {'RaiseError' => 1}) || die "$DBI::errstr";` we need to figure out where the problem indeed is

Comment: When i try to run simply the program it says oracle.so not found so i wrapped as  a executable so that it may include all dependency,To make it simple from the system am connecting from will not have oracle instance

Comment: so what does it say with modification I suggested?

Comment: I mean add 'die' and re-compile

Comment: install_driver(Oracle) failed: Can't load '/opt/ActivePerl-5.12/lib/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so' for module DBD::Oracle: libclntsh.so.10.1:  I have put all the needed DBI perl modules but stiil the same error

Comment: I believe this is the compilation  issue. Just install everything is requires to  your remote host